# Create Products with overlayed images from the default images

Tags: 7, commerce, media

I'm using D7 and Commerce. I want the ability to create products based off a default image for a product type & image that our designers will upload to create the final product. Think of something like zazzle.com.

[Imagecache_Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) I've used this module before for the 'overlay' feature butit didn't work as desired. Its Possible I didn't set it up correctly. (This might be the key to the answer)

How can I create a product that uses the combined 'default image' & an uploaded design used to overlay and combine as the final image for a product?

Would also like the ability to place to adjust the position and size of the overlay image.

Answer (score 3):

[Image Cache Actions](https://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) will allow you to set up image styles that overlay images onto another preset image, such as a T Shirt template.

For your own designers, using Photoshop to place the designs on a template is probably a much better option than having them mess about with a web app.

For customers, [Commerce Custom Product](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) looks like it might be the submission flow you're looking for, but you'll need your customers to submit high res designs for you to work with on the product you're shipping - and you'll need to test this to destruction on different browsers and devices.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to give an example with the Image Cache Actions>